# Twig rule for alternating between two div classes

Tags: html, css, twig

First of all, I'm not a programmer/web designer, and I'm just making a small fan site, so I'm sorry if it seems that I put too little effort in trying to do this myself.

Basically, I'm trying to modify a site template in a way so it would show news thumbnails not just on the right side of the article preview, but would alternate between left and right. The template uses HTML, CSS, and Twig. **imageholder-right** and **imageholder-left** are valid CSS classes.

This is how it originally was:

```
        {% if record.image!="" %}
            <div class="large-4 imageholder-right">
                <a href="{{ image(record.image) }}">
                    <img src="{{ thumbnail(record.image, 400, 260) }}">
                </a>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
```

This is what I attempted to do so it could function like I want to:

```
        {% if record.image!="" %}
            {% set imagepos = 'right' %}
            {% if imagepos == right %}
                <div class="large-4 imageholder-left">
                    <a href="{{ image(record.image) }}">
                        <img src="{{ thumbnail(record.image, 400, 260) }}">
                    </a>
                </div>
                {% set imagepos = 'left' %}
            {% else %}
                <div class="large-4 imageholder-right">
                    <a href="{{ image(record.image) }}">
                        <img src="{{ thumbnail(record.image, 400, 260) }}">
                    </a>
                </div>  
                {% set imagepos = 'right' %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
```

However, with this code every image preview remains on the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could give a look at `{% loop.index %}`.

[Twig - Loops](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html)

I guess your code is in a loop?

**Edit:**

As @DarkBee suggested, the cleanest way is to use `<div class="large-4 imageholder-{{ loop.index is even ? 'right' : 'left' }}">`.

```
{% for record in records %}
    {% if record.image != "" %}
        <div class="large-4 imageholder-{{ loop.index is even ? 'right' : 'left' }}">
            <a href="{{ image(record.image) }}">
                <img src="{{ thumbnail(record.image, 400, 260) }}">
            </a>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: (P.S. yes, it was in a loop, I just didn't paste the respective part of code)

Comment: Are you using this or your solution? Because your solution duplicate some codes, and it's best to avoid this.

Comment: I'm using Bolt CMS, which is free and welcomed to alter.

Comment: I meant the code. See my edit if you don't want the if to be in middle of the class string.

Comment: Oh, lol. Sorry, I got this now. At first, I didn't even notice that you proposed your own code. I just thought you invited me to take a look at {% loop.index %}, and I came up with the solution of my own (obviously, not perfect). Thanks, I'll use yours then.

Comment: Ahhhh! This explains the confusion! I in fact edited my answer short after to give you an example of what it would looks like. Anyway, good to know it's now working! :)

Comment: Could go with `<div class="large-4 imageholder-{{ loop.index is even ? 'right' : 'left' }}">` as well btw

Comment: @DarkBee Yes in fact, I will edit my answer accordingly since this is the cleanest way up to now, thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for list in field.meta('services') %}
{% set counter = (counter | default(0)) + 1 %}
  <div id="service-{{counter}}" class="service {% if loop.index % 2 %}transform {% endif %}">
    <div class="div-left">
        <img src="{{Image(list.image).src}}" alt="{{Image(list.image).alt}}" class="img-responsive {% if not loop.index % 2 %}transform {% endif %}" />
    </div>
    <div class="div-right {% if loop.index % 2 %}transform {% endif %}">
      <h1>{{list.service_name}}</h1>
      <p>{{list.service_content}}</p> 
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

In the above code if the *loop.index* is divisible to 2 or we can say is even then it adds the class "**transform**" to the div otherwise it is not adding any class to the div.

```
loop.index % 2
```

means the *loop index* is divided by 2. the index of ***For loop*** starts from Zero(0).

if we need to make the condition reverse like an odd *loop.index* will add the transform class and then use the ***if condition*** like:

```
{% if not loop.index % 2 %}transform{% endif %}
```

in your case you can write the condition like:

```
class="{% if loop.index % 2 %}imageholder-left{% else %}imageholder-right{% endif %}"
```